# SQL Query looking at multiple rows in 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

New to SQL.  Looking to create a SQL query that returns a value to see if an action is occurring 3 times daily

Example Table:

| ID | Task | Date_performed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | A | 1/2/2021 |
| 1 | A | 1/2/2021 |
| 1 | A | 1/2/2021 |
| 1 | A | 1/3/2021 |

Hopeful End Result:

| ID | Task | Date | Compliance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2021 | N |
| 1 | A | 1/2/2021 | Y |
| 1 | A | 1/3/2021 | N |

The task was complete TWICE on 1/1/21 so it would not be compliant.  The task was completed THREE times on 1/2/21 so it would be compliant.  And finally the task was completed ONCE on 1/3/21 so it would not be compliant.

UPDATE:

In trying all the suggested code, I am pretty much getting the same results in which it looks like each row is being looked at individually so they are all returning non-complaint.  Please see my updated information above as it is probably a better explanation.

Results:

| ID | Task | Date | Compliance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2021 | N |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2021 | N |
| 1 | A | 1/2/2021 | N |
| 1 | A | 1/2/2021 | N |
| 1 | A | 1/2/2021 | N |
| 1 | A | 1/3/2021 | N |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Relational DBMS (Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: What if it's completed once on day 1 and three times on day 2?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f51cb7baa74155f0004d902b6e6fd5c3

Comment: @MatBailie, well, I tried them all (yours too.) Don't remember which order.

Comment: This change of question was substantial – that's pretty problematic as it invalidates all answers given so far...

Comment: The results at the end of the question also make no sense. Why is there now NO instances of compliance=Y?

Comment: Voting to close this question as edits materially change what is being asked. In such cases a different question should be asked, not an edit that completely invalidates all existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you need here is a case statement and an aggerate function

Grouping by ID, Task and Date_performed we count the number of completed tasks and display the proper value accordingly

```
SELECT ID, Task, Date_performed, case when count(Task) >= 3 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Compliance
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, Task, Date_performed
```

edit: I added the date to the select clause because it makes sense if we are checking if the task was completed 3 times daily to know which dates

if a task failing on any date constitutes non compliance, you can use the same aggregate function and check if any date fails, like so

```
SELECT ID, Task, case when sum(Compliance) = 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Compliance
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Task, Date_performed, case when count(Task) >= 3 then 0 else 1 end as Compliance
    FROM table
    GROUP BY ID, Task, Date_performed 
) as data
GROUP BY ID, Task
```

Comment: And if `true`/`false` is fine as well, can be simplified to `SELECT id, task, count(*) >= 3 FROM ...`

Comment: @Aconcagua i don't believe that's valid in sql server, but i could be wrong

Comment: Upvoted??? Why?

Comment: Hm. for MS SQL I cannot speak. Postgre accepts…

Comment: This would give two rows of results for ID1, which is not the correct output

Comment: @Aconcagua, but it doesn't. Returns 4 rows.

Comment: @MatBailie you are correct! ive edited my answer

Comment: Use integer literals for integer values.

Comment: @jarlh whoops, fixed. ty

Comment: I have updated my question to hopefully be clearer.  Using your code I am returning results for each row rather than by date (if that makes sense).  Please see my updated information above.  TY!

Answer (score 1):

I would aggregate twice. Once to find the count of completions per day, and then again to one row per ID/Task.

```
WITH
  daily AS
(
  SELECT
    id, task, date_performed, COUNT(*) AS completed
  FROM
    your_data
  GROUP BY
    id, task, date_performed
)
SELECT
  id,
  task,
  CASE WHEN MIN(completed) >= 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END  AS compliance
FROM
  daily
GROUP BY
  id,
  task
```

The above code asserts that EVERY day with a task completion must have at least 3 completions (if any day has 1 or 2, it's non compliant).

This can be changed to "at least one (or more) of the days" requiring 3 or more completions, by changing `MIN` to `MAX`.

Comment: I have updated my question to hopefully be clearer.  Using your code I am returning results for each row rather than by date (if that makes sense).  Please see my updated information above.  TY!

Comment: @dustinrodriguez I don't understand your comment, or the edit to your question. This answer certainly does return the results your original question requested, including one instance of compliant=Y : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f79ec138e9e168b2b6612e964978384a

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following perhaps, using count over a *window* to include the date for the daily- criteria.

```
with x as (
    select *, 
      case when Count(*) over(partition by id, Task, Date_performed)>=3 
        then 'Y' else 'N' 
      end Compliance
    from t
)
select id, Task, Compliance
from x
group by id, Task, Compliance
```

See [Working DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2235e73680071f8dd15b077a1bca8953)

Answer (score 0):

We can group by id, task and date and count the occurrences to determine if we comply or not for each arbitrary day:

```
SELECT
  id, task, date_performed,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS compliance
FROM example GROUP BY id, task, date_performed
```

Comment: since 'Y' > 'N' wouldn't you want to go with `MIN(compliance)` to catch the N?

Comment: @RobertJuneau Depends – are you fine with *any* of the days complying or do you require *all* of them? I assumed the former, the latter would require the minimum.

Comment: @RobertJuneau Obsolete, question changed in the meanwhile... Updated the answer to new version of question.